# 2000 Honda prelude radiator issue

Tags: honda, coolant, radiator, prelude, no-crank-no-start

I was driving my Honda prelude and all of a sudden it shut down and wouldn't start again. I pushed the vehicle to the side of the street and opened the hood. The radiator frame where the hose connected to was busted. No steam or overheating warnings came from the vehicle while driving. Is there more than just the radiator as it being the problem for reasons it won't start? Is the thermostat gone also and is that why there was no indication when driving that vehicle may have been overheating? It was very weird though that no smoke or steam was coming from the engine when it broke down. Could you offer some assistance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. First question is do you have any coolant in the system? Does the engine turn over when you try to start it? Do your other power systems (lights, fans, radio etc.) still work? There could be a number of reasons that the motor dies that don't involve the cooling system.

Comment: Does it sound like it has compression when cranking?

Comment: Yes there was coolant in the system. Engine just died on the road. Won't turn over, radio, lights work.

Comment: You please share pictures of the internals

Comment: The coolant would of had to hit the engine for there to be steam, if the Crack was on the radiator and it poured directly on the ground that would explain no coolant - no steam

Comment: If you were driving when it shut down there should of been symptoms before hand, can you give us anymore information, Heavy or weak idle, hesitation, surging, flickering lights ?

Answer (score 0):

What I got from the points you mentioned above is that there is something that hit the hose  and maybe it also hit a wire (cam or crank shaft wire ?) which caused it to cut off the engine. If the car did not overheat, even when there is no coolant inside the radiator, the car should still start.